# Viewing failure triggers in Rails system tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest, system-testing

I have an [ActionController::TestCase](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionController/TestCase.html) that's failing and I don't know why.

```
require 'test_helper'
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

  setup do
    @user = users(:bob)
    sign_in @user
  end

  test "should create user" do
    assert_difference('User.count') do
      post :create, user: { 
        first_name: 'Alice',
        email: 'alice@example.com',
        password: 'adflihbrgshbart'
      }
    end
  end
end
```

The result is

```
Failure:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_create_user [.../dev/test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:23]
Minitest::Assertion: "User.count" didn't change by 1.
Expected: 5
  Actual: 4
```

Is there a way to have [post](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-post) show me what the errors? For instance, is there a way I can access `errors` array to call `errors.full_messages` that'd normally be available in the resulting view when there's an error?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the controller instance variables using `assign`, so it should be possible to access errors for that instance variable and test full_messages.  This may not work if the reason the record wasn't created was because some `before_action` prevented `create` from being called.   But you can test if that happens with the 'pry' gem and making `binding.pry` the first line of the create.

In any case, to examine the instance variable...

```
  post :create, user: { 
    first_name: 'Alice',
    email: 'alice@example.com',
    password: 'adflihbrgshbart'
  }
  assert([], assign[:user].errors.full_messages)
```